# How to run app on startup as different user?

Tags: root, startup, minecraft

i have MineCraft server and i need run it everytime i start Debian. I solved it, but it always run as root. I need it run as normal user. Does somebody have idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should ask on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Run it with:

```
sudo -u {username} {fileToRun}
```